# Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'. fetching data

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to fetch image from database and i am getting this error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'.

here is my code

```
job.CompanyLogo = "data:Image/jpg;base64,"+ Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])rdr["CompanyLogo"]);
```

note. i have saved image in database in bytes

Comment: _"...i have saved image in database in bytes..."_, you do not say which ORM or data access tech you're using but I'd double check that.

Comment: i would think rdr["CompanyLogo"] is coming as a string value and when you are trying to cast it to byte[] ..it is erroring out.

Comment: You can get the string as a byte[] by using this `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rdr["CompanyLogo"])` Just be sure to use the correct encoding for whatever your source string type is.